# How to retrieve opened job listing on LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

Currently you can retrieve job listing from LinkedIn using this endpoint :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates?event-type=job-posting&format=xml
```

However this listing differs slightly from the company careers page and most important doesn't provide a way to filter out closed offers.

Is there some options that can be set up to avoid retrieving those ?
Is it something possible through LinkedIn partner program ?